# How to pass variables to layout from handlebars?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, layout, handlebars.js

I am using handlbars with express/nodejs, and is possible to pass variables individually to the views, but i dont find a way to pass to general layout. How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What is general layout for you?)
As I know Handlebars is a templates engine.
We have a template, we pass variables to it, we got a string with hardcoded variables inside. Templates don't have common scope or something like this. Template engine just helps you to fill string content easier. (html is a string)

But you can create a scope inside of your code and use the same variables for different templates.

Comment: I call template as layout, you are right. I need to pass a variable to the main template and this value is used in all views.